# bring my DNN azure website back to a previous date

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I messed up my DNN azure website by deleting my modules and want to go back to a previous date. I've heard this was possible and have searched the web for several days, not finding an answer.

Comment: I tried restoring from the recycle bin, but nothing came back and now the recycle bin is empty.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this issue might belong to DNN. Here is a similar thread [restore-deleted-module-from-database-recycle-bin](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/322995/scope/posts/restore-deleted-module-from-database-recycle-bin) in DNN support forums, you could refer to it.
 If a module is deleted from a page, the IsDeleted field in the Modules table is sat to true. If it gets restored from the Recycle Bin, it would be sat to false. Please try to find that whether you could find the modules you deleted in your Modules table.

Comment: When I try to create new or existing module it seems there are none there.  Would you mind explaining a little further how to reset the module table to true?  I believe I found the module table under (find more modules, installed extensions) but I don't see anything about deleted modules. When I go to (expandable text/html) I do see the name of some of my modules I created which were the forms I created. These do still show up on my pages.  But, all HTML modules  with content and images are nowhere to be found.